# Array replace numeric and associative

Tags: php

I have a variable which containts comma separated values like this: `$str = "1,5";`

To convert it to array I have the following code:

```
$str = "1,5";
$replacements = explode(',', $str);
```

Now the array looks like following:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 5
)
```

I have this another array: `$base = array('1'=>'Bread','5'=>'Butter');`

What I am trying to do is replace the values of the numeric array with the value of associative array above based on the `key` of the associative array and the value of the numeric array and it should look like following:

```
// This is what I am trying to achive
Array
(
  [0] => Bread  // because 1 = Bread in the assoc. array
  [1] => Butter // because 5 = Butter in  the assoc. array
)
```

To achive this ,I tried the following code:

```
$str = "1,5";
$replacements = explode(',', $str);         
$base = array('1'=>'Bread','5'=>'Butter');          
$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements);      
print_r($basket);
```

But it is giving me the following output:

```
 Array
(
[1] => 5
[5] => Butter
[0] => 1
)
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: So you want  $base sorted by $replacements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = "1,5";
$replacements = explode(',', $str);         
$base = array('1'=>'Bread','5'=>'Butter');   
$basket = array();

foreach($replacements as $value) {
    $basket[]=$base[$value];
}
```

Comment: I downvoted the answer, because of the reason the PHP function is there to do this, see @Brad Christie answer. Also it is not complety safe

Comment: @Hendriq I like doing it this way because it allows for fine control say that you have two different arrays and need to combine say first name and last name together into full name. i know that is not the situation here, but it allows for easy modification like that.

Comment: @Hendriq: How is it not "safe"?  Also, what if `$str` was `"5,1"`?

Comment: @Seth McClaine Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly and even if the value of `$str` is `"5,1";` I have tried with more values in `$str` and changed the order and it still worked :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @black_belt: if the order is what you're after, just `$replacements = explode(','$str); sort($replacements);`?

Answer (score 4):

`array_replace` compares the keys of the two arrays, not the values to the keys.

Try `array_map`.

```
$basket = array_map(function($a) use($base){
    return $base[$a];
}, $replacements);
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/xPhoZP

Comment: I do love this solution, even though it relies on PHP >= 5.3. ;p

Comment: @BradChristie: I hope no one is using 5.2 or less :-P

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Have a look at [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). This method allows you to use one array as the keys and another as the values. then you can use `array_values($base)` to only grab the values portion and combine from there.</strike>

Okay, after a couple sips of coffee, here ya go using built-in methods:

- `array_intersect_keys` Pulls matches from one array based on key matches from another.
- `array_fill_keys` convert your `$replacements` array in to `array(1=>0,5=>0)` so we can use it in `array_intersect_keys`.

Code:

```
$str = "1,5";

$replacements = explode(',', $str);
$base = array(
  1 => 'Bread',
  2 => 'Gravy',
  3 => 'Stuffing',
  4 => 'Turkey',
  5 => 'Butter',
  6 => 'Squash'
);

var_dump(array_intersect_key($base, array_fill_keys($replacements,0)));
```

result:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Bread"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Butter"
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/o2IQZX)

and as @nickb pointed out in a comment, if you want the keys to be `[0],[1]` just call `array_values` on the result. Also, if order is important, maybe call an `sort` on `$replacements` before getting in to the fetching.

Comment: Nice use of the PHP functiones them self

Comment: What if `$str` was `"5,1"`?

Comment: `array_intersect_key()` you say?! Brilliant! `:P` The only downside here is the keys don't match the OP's output, you'd need an `array_values()` call, but who knows, OP might not need the keys to be reset.

Comment: @nickb: It's funny; I probably took too long to get there, but if it's any consolation I didn't see your post until just now. haha. though a HUGE benefactor was (in)sufficient coffee consumption.

Comment: @nickb: I also took the long way and used `array_fill` over flip. You're right about keys, but oh well at this point. I'm calling it quits for the day as _clearly_ my fingers and/or mind have had enough. The good news? If you asked me to do this in C# with LINQ I'd have no problem; I'm in that stuff all the time these days. ;p

Comment: I like this answer!  It's clever :)

Answer (score 2):

If you [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) the array you `explode()`'d, you can get some interesting results:

```
$flipped = array_flip( explode(',', $str));
```

**Result:**

```
Array 
( 
    [1] => 0 
    [5] => 1 
)
```

Now, you can intersect your `$base` array and the `$flipped` array on keys with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key):

```
$intersection = array_intersect_key( $base, $flipped);
```

**Result:**

```
Array 
( 
    [1] => Bread 
    [5] => Butter 
)
```

Then, just reset the indexes with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values): *(may or may not be necessary, if you don't care about the indexes, then omit this step)*

```
$replacements = array_values( $intersection);
```

Or, in a single line:

```
$str = "1,5";
$base = array('1'=>'Bread','5'=>'Butter');
$replacements = array_values( array_intersect_key( $base, array_flip( explode(',', $str))));
```

This [prints](http://3v4l.org/XCTRo#v510):

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Bread 
    [1] => Butter 
)
```

Comment: `array_filp`?  Very clever!  +1

Comment: thanks for your answer. if `$str = "5,1";` it doesn't provide proper order.

Comment: @black_belt - If that order was important, it's a very important detail you omitted from your question :) My solution is using the ordering within `$base` as a priority, if your desire is to have the ordering of `$str`, then changes can be made.

Comment: @nickb . Thanks for your reply. I think I made it clear in my question :) by this >" What I am trying to do is replace the values of the numeric array with the value of associative array above based on the `key of the associative array` and `the value of the numeric array` and it should look like following" :)

Comment: @black_belt - My answer fulfils those requirements, and mimics your example output. However, your original post fails to mention that the order within the `$str` must be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$basket=array();
foreach($replacements as $value) {
   array_push($basket, $base[$value]);
}
print_r($basket);
```

Hopefully it works.